# large difference between a pytorch model accuracy using cpu vs gpu for training

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, cpu

I trained the same PyTorch model in an ubuntu system with GPU tesla k80 and I got an accuracy of about 32% but when I run it using CPU the accuracy is 43%.
the Cuda-toolkit and cudnn library are also installed.
nvidia-driver:
470.63.01

nvcc version:
10.1

what are the possible reasons for this large difference?

For more detail, i used this code https://github.com/copenlu/xformer-multi-source-domain-adaptation and adapted this for my question-answering problem
the model class is:

```
class MultiViewTransformerNetworkAveragingIndividuals(nn.Module):
   
    Multi-view transformer network for domain adaptation
   

    def __init__(self, bert_model, bert_config, n_domains: int = 2, n_classes: int = 2):
        super(MultiViewTransformerNetworkAveragingIndividuals, self).__init__()
        
        self.domain_experts = nn.ModuleList([AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(bert_model,config=bert_config) for _ in range(n_domains)])
        self.shared_bert = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(bert_model,config=bert_config)

        self.n_domains = n_domains
        self.n_classes = n_classes

        # Default weight is averaging
        self.weights = [1. / (self.n_domains + 1)] * (self.n_domains + 1)

        self.average = False

    def forward(
            self,
            input_ids: torch.LongTensor,
            attention_mask: torch.LongTensor,
            head_mask=None,
            inputs_embeds=None,
            start_positions=None,
            end_positions=None,
            output_attentions=None,
            output_hidden_states=None,
            return_dict=None,
            domains: torch.LongTensor = None,
            return_logits: bool = False
    ):
        
        outputs = self.shared_bert(input_ids, attention_mask,head_mask=head_mask,inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,return_dict=return_dict)
        logits_shared_start = outputs[0]
        logits_shared_end = outputs[1]
        
        softmax = nn.Softmax()

        if not self.average:
            if domains is not None:   
                logits = self.domain_experts[domains[0]](input_ids, attention_mask,head_mask=head_mask,inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,return_dict=return_dict)
                logits_start=logits[0]
                logits_end=logits[1]
                # b x n_dom(+1) x nclasses
                start_preds = softmax(logits_start)
                end_preds = softmax(logits_end)
            else:
                
                logits_start = logits_shared_start
                logits_end = logits_shared_end
                # b x n_dom(+1) x nclasses
                start_preds = softmax(logits_start)
                end_preds = softmax(logits_end)
                
        else:
            logits_private = [self.domain_experts[d](input_ids, attention_mask,head_mask=head_mask,inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,return_dict=return_dict) for d in
                              range(self.n_domains)]
            logits_private_start=[log_private[0] for log_private in logits_private]
            logits_private_end=[log_private[1] for log_private in logits_private]
            logits_start = logits_private_start + [logits_shared_start]
            logits_end = logits_private_end + [logits_shared_end]
            if return_logits:
                return (logits_start,logits_end)
            attn = torch.FloatTensor(self.weights).view(1, -1, 1) 
           
            # b x n_dom(+1) x nclasses
            start_preds = torch.stack([softmax(logs) for logs in logits_start], dim=1)
            end_preds = torch.stack([softmax(logs) for logs in logits_end], dim=1)
            # Apply attention
            start_preds = torch.sum(start_preds * attn, dim=1)
            end_preds = torch.sum(end_preds * attn, dim=1)
        
        
        outputs = (start_preds,end_preds,)
        loss=None
        if start_positions is not None and end_positions is not None:
            if len(start_positions.size()) > 1:
                start_positions = start_positions.squeeze(-1)
            if len(end_positions.size()) > 1:
                end_positions = end_positions.squeeze(-1)
            # sometimes the start/end positions are outside our model inputs, we ignore these terms
            ignored_index = start_preds.size(1)
            start_positions.clamp_(0, ignored_index)
            end_positions.clamp_(0, ignored_index)
            
            # LogSoftmax + NLLLoss
            loss_fn = nn.NLLLoss()
            xent = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            s_loss =  loss_fn(torch.log(start_preds), start_positions)
            e_loss =  loss_fn(torch.log(end_preds), end_positions)
            loss_s=(s_loss+e_loss/2)
            loss=loss_s
            s_loss_t=xent(logits_shared_start, start_positions)
            e_loss_t=xent(logits_shared_end, end_positions)
            loss_t=(s_loss_t+e_loss_t)/2
            loss+=loss_t
            # Strong supervision on in domain
            #if domains is not None:
            
        return QuestionAnsweringModelOutput(
            loss=loss,
            start_logits=start_preds,
            end_logits=end_preds,
        )
```

when I run this code step bt step the output of model (start_logits, end_logits and loss) are different from cpu to gpu running.

it should be noted that the seeds are initialized in the first of program as:

```
# Set all the seeds
    seed = args.seed
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
```

and the results do not change in multiple runs.

Comment: it is impossible to answer without context details, such as model architecture, dataset, training pipeline, etc.

Comment: I edited this to include more details

Comment: Its not impossible to answer since we know op is using cudnn which already makes reproducibility an issue.

Comment: I have no reproducibility issue because when running the program with CPU always get 43% accuracy and when I run the program with GPU always get 32%. the problem is this difference between CPU and GPU

Answer (score 0):

According to Nvidia's CUDNN [documentation page](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/developer-guide/index.html#reproducibility):

> 8. Reproducibility (determinism) By design, most of cuDNN routines from a given version generate the same bit-wise results across runs
>    when executed on GPUs with the same architecture and the same number
>    of SMs. However, bit-wise reproducibility is not guaranteed across
>    versions, as the implementation of a given routine may change. With
>    the current release, the following routines do not guarantee
>    reproducibility because they use atomic operations:
>
>    - `cudnnConvolutionBackwardFilter` when `CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_BWD_FILTER_ALGO_0` or `CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_BWD_FILTER_ALGO_3` is used
>    - `cudnnConvolutionBackwardData` when `CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_BWD_DATA_ALGO_0` is used
>    - `cudnnPoolingBackward` when `CUDNN_POOLING_MAX` is used
>    - `cudnnSpatialTfSamplerBackward`
>    - `cudnnCTCLoss` and `cudnnCTCLoss_v8` when `CUDNN_CTC_LOSS_ALGO_NON_DETERMINSTIC` is used

So even though you are using `deterministic = true` on the cudnn, some operations are not deterministic.

Try disabling cudnn and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I added this:
" torch.backends.cudnn.enabled=False" but the results did not changed